C# EPPlus - Export list into an Excel report
I have the following models:
public class ECUPartHistory
{
    public int PartHistID { get; set; }
    public string ECUName { get; set; }
    public string Sprint { get; set; }
    public string ECURelease { get; set; }
    public string ECUVariant { get; set; }
    public string LUPartNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Carlines> Carlines { get; set; }
}

public class Carlines
{
    public Nullable<int> CarlineID { get; set; }
    public string CarLineName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> From { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> To { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ChangeYear { get; set; }

}

I would like to convert the data from these models into an Excel using EPPlus. Following is the expected format.
Sample excel format

Which .net core version you use?

In your screenshot what are 167M2 and BR223 ?

I've used EPPlus.Core library to achieve the below. You can install the same via nuget package manager console:
Install-Package EPPlus.Core


Refer more to the above package here

Refer the below code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;

public class ECUPartHistory
{
    public string ECUName { get; set; }
    public string Sprint { get; set; }
    public string ECURelease { get; set; }
    public string ECUVariant { get; set; }
    public string LUPartNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Carlines> Carlines { get; set; }
}

public class Carlines
{
    public string CarLineName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> From { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> To { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ChangeYear { get; set; }
}


public static class ExcelGenerator
{
    public static byte[] GenerateExcel(List<ECUPartHistory> ecuPartHistories)
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ECU Part History");

            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ECU Name";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Sprint";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "ECU Release";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "ECU Variant";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "LU Part Number";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Carline Name";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "From";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "To";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 9].Value = "Change Year";

            int row = 2;
            foreach (var history in ecuPartHistories)
            {
                foreach (var carline in history.Carlines)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = history.ECUName;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = history.Sprint;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = history.ECURelease;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = history.ECUVariant;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value = history.LUPartNumber;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = carline.CarLineName;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = carline.From.HasValue ? carline.From.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Value = carline.To.HasValue ? carline.To.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 9].Value = carline.ChangeYear.HasValue ? carline.ChangeYear.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                    row++;
                }
            }


            using (var range = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 9])
            {
                range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
            }

            worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

            return package.GetAsByteArray();
        }
    }
}



public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ecuPartHistories = new List<ECUPartHistory>
        {
            new ECUPartHistory
            {
                ECUName = "ECU1",
                Sprint = "Sprint1",
                ECURelease = "Release1",
                ECUVariant = "Variant1",
                LUPartNumber = "Part1",
                Carlines = new List<Carlines>
                {
                    new Carlines { CarLineName = "CarLine1", From = 2020, To = 2021, ChangeYear = 2020 },
                    new Carlines { CarLineName = "CarLine2", From = 2021, To = 2022, ChangeYear = 2021 }
                }
            },
            new ECUPartHistory
            {
                ECUName = "ECU2",
                Sprint = "Sprint2",
                ECURelease = "Release2",
                ECUVariant = "Variant2",
                LUPartNumber = "Part2",
                Carlines = new List<Carlines>
                {
                    new Carlines { CarLineName = "CarLine3", From = 2019, To = 2020, ChangeYear = 2019 },
                    new Carlines { CarLineName = "CarLine4", From = 2020, To = 2021, ChangeYear = 2020 }
                }
            }
        };

        var fileContents = ExcelGenerator.GenerateExcel(ecuPartHistories);
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ECUPartHistoryNew.xlsx");

        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileContents);
       
    }

}

The above code will give a sample Excel like below :

PS: I've used .net core version 8 as the target framework with EPPluc.Core 1.5.4
Hope it helps :-)
